# Importing data into a project with a custom CRS incorrectly projected

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I created a custom CRS for a project I am working on.  I then started a new project, set to my custom CRS and turn on "on the fly" transformation.  I import Rail data that I know is in my custom CRS, and it imports as expected.  However when I import Road data from our library that is in a different CRS, this data goes to a totally different area.

I tried the reverse situation.  I opened the Road data in a new project, set the CRS to this layer and turn on "on the fly" transformation.  When I import the Rail data (which is in my custom CRS) it imports fine.

Is it possible to create a project based on a Custom CRS?

Ultimately I want to import the data I am interested in, convert it to my custom CRS so I can test out some of the grass functions (which I understand needs to be in the same CRS), and use qconsolidate to store it is a separate location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to change your settings under `Settings -> Options, CRS`, CRS for new layers to `Prompt for CRS`

You can rightclick on every layer -> `Set CRS for Layer` and check that your rail data has the custom CRS, but road data another CRS as stated for your library.

If the data comes as shapefiles, they should have the correct .prj file with projection information. CSV files are usually imported into the project CRS, unless you change the preferences as mentioned above.

If you are unsure which data is correct, change the project CRS to EPSG:3857, and load Openstreetmap or Google layer with the Openlayers plugin as background to see which layer fits to that.

Once you are sure that all layers are correct, you can rightclick -> `Save As ...` to your custom CRS, add that file as new layer, delete the old layer and the Openlayers layers, and change project CRS back to your custom CRS.

If all layers have the same CRS, you can uncheck On-the-fly-reprojection, and the layers should remain in their places.

---

Below you see a comparison of the different Australian Datum systems at a scale of 1:2000:

[image]

Green grid lines are WGS84 (equvalent to GGA94), red is AGD66 with

`+proj=longlat +ellps=aust_SA +towgs84=-117.808,-51.536,137.784,0.303,0.446,0.234,-0.29 +no_defs`

and blue one is AGD84 with

```
+proj=longlat +ellps=aust_SA +towgs84=-134,-48,149,0,0,0,0 +no_defs
```

The green grid is 168m south and 122 metres west of the other two. Red and blue are just 1 meter apart. These offsets may vary across the continent.

Comment: Thanks Andre, I tried these suggestions but I couldn't get it to work. I think I am doing something incorrect whereby my custom data is in metres, but my other data defaults to longitude/latitude - it always seems to import at the origin.

Comment: With lon/lat coordinates, the CRS of the other data has to be EPSG:4326, so it has to go in a separate layer. How does your custom CRS definition look like?

Comment: My custom CRS is similar to below, but with a different Lon_0 as my site is in a different zone.   I bring the other data in by the "Add vector layer" command.                   +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=141 +k_0=0.999940 +x_0=300000.000000 +y_0=5000000.000000 +ellps=ANS +a=6378160.0 +b=6356774.719 +f=298.25 +units=m +no_defs no_defs <>

Comment: The ellipsoid shoud be aust_SA, you can ommit a,b and f then. Is your other data a shapefile? Does it have the right .prj file? You can look into that with any text editor.

Comment: I will try changing the ellipsoid tonight.  My data has the following PRJ info for the Road Layer I am interested. (GEOGCS["GCS_GDA_1994",DATUM["D_GDA_1994",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]])

Comment: The offset between GDA94 and WGS84 is less than 1 meter, so EPSG:4326 should fit for the road data.

Comment: I changed the ellipsoid as suggested. My data in native ISG format was loaded correctly and I could confirm the coordinates where exactly right.  However when I imported the above data (on GDA94) this data was about 150-200m out from where I expected (in comparison to an aerial image in ISG).  <br/> On another [post] (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91083/can-you-create-a-crs-of-superseded-nsw-datum) there is a suggestion that AGD66, which this CRS is based on, is incorrect.  To rectify, to I also need to modify the CRS for AGD66?

Comment: If the ISG data is based on AGD66, it should have non-zero +towgs84 values. For GDA94, these are all zero. To avoid misinterpretation, you should add those zeroes to the GDA94 projection. Datum transformation is only correct if both CRS have full +towgs84 parameters. Note that the .prj file does not contain any towgs84 values.

Comment: I added the +towgs84 values from AGD66 (upon which my datum is based) and this has appeared to work (ie my data overlays correctly.  I note that omiting the A, b and f parameters, resulted in incorrect project. Therefore I essentially left these in as per the following, which seems to work. (+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=151 +k_0=0.999940 +x_0=300000.000000 +y_0=5000000.000000 +ellps=aust_SA +a=6378160.0 +b=6356774.719 +f=298.25 +units=m +towgs84=-117.808,-51.536,137.784,0.303,0.446,0.234,-0.29+no_defs  no_defs <>)